# Find the determinant after a certain row operation is applied to a matrix with known determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, determinant

$A = \begin{bmatrix} --a--\\ --b--\\ --c-- \end{bmatrix}$

$A$ is a $3\times3$ matrix. The rows are all different, and the first row is called $a$. The second row is called $b$. The third row is called $c$. I'm not saying that all the values in the first row are the same, I am simply saying that the first row is called $a$. The determinant is $not$ $0$.

If the $\det(A)=3$, what is the determinant of:

$\begin{bmatrix} --a+b--\\ --b+c--\\ --c+a-- \end{bmatrix}$

I thought about this, but I recalled that whenever you have a matrix, and you add a row multiple of another, the **determinant** does not change. However in this case, the answer in the back of my textbook is $6$ and I don't understand how?

Comment: And... **what matrix is** $\;A\;$ **itself** ?

Comment: It doesn't matter

Comment: A is a $3\times 3$ matrix

Comment: @K Either you don't understand the question, or you're kidding...or I don't understand the question: how come it isn't relevant?!

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Oh, so **it does matter, after all...** !

Comment: Well I guess kind of, cause you need to know where the $c$ and $b$ come from, but other then that it isn't of much use

Comment: SO $\;A\;$ is $\;3\times 3\;$ matrix, with first row all $\;a\;$ , second row all $\;b\;$ ,etc.?

Comment: I suppose that is the case. But again, what $a$ is doesn't matter here

Comment: @Don, but (of course) if that's the case, then the determinant of $A$ is zero.

Comment: I'm not sure that $every$ element is the case, I suppose they are just saying that the first row is filled with values, second row is, and third row is.

Comment: That's why they gave the original $det(A)=3$, so its not the $0$ determinant case

Comment: @GerryMyerson **exactly my point, thank you**! As it is, the question is pretty confusing and, perhaps, even nonsensical...

Comment: I think, K, that you had better write out the entire question as you have found it, not leaving out the least little bit, since what you have written so far is nonsense.

Comment: @KSplitX I propose you to write down **explicitly** your matrices. Don't save your time and waste ours.

Comment: Okay I will update it in the quetsion

Comment: I didn't think that information would be useful, but okay I will do that now

Comment: Wow, what a difference when people can see what the question really was!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a+b \\ b+c \\ c+a\end{bmatrix}$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{vmatrix}a+b \\ b+c \\ c+a\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1\end{vmatrix}\begin{vmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{vmatrix} = 2 \times 3 = 6$$

Comment: Where did the get the $\times 2$ from?

Comment: @KSplitX $\begin{vmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1\end{vmatrix} = 2$

Comment: Determinant is 2. Okay thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lets do it with rows instead of columns and remember that the determinant is multilinear:

\begin{align}
\det(a+b,b+c,c+a) = \quad &\det(a,b,c)+\det(a,b,a)\\
+&\det(a,c,c)+ \det(a,c,a)\\
+&\det(b,b,c)+ \det(b,b,a)\\
+&\det(b,c,c)+ \det(b,c,a).
\end{align}

All terms except the first and the last vanish because there is the same entry twice. And because rearranging the rows does not change the determinant you will find

$$\det(a+b,b+c,c+a)=\det(a,b,c)+\det(b,c,a)=2\det(a,b,c).$$

In your case $\det(A)=3$, so $2\cdot\det(A)=6$ is the result.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with the explantion you added (and the one you also deleted...) it is finally clearer what you meant, but then, since the determinant of a matrix with two identical rows is zero, and if we intechange two rows we multiply the determinant by $\;-1\;$ , by multilinearity we get:$${}$$

$$\det\begin{pmatrix}-a+b-\\-b+c-\\-c+a-\end{pmatrix}=\color{red}{\det\begin{pmatrix}-a-\\-b-\\-c-\end{pmatrix}}+\underbrace{\det\begin{pmatrix}-a-\\-b-\\-a-\end{pmatrix}+\det\begin{pmatrix}-a-\\-c-\\-c-\end{pmatrix}+\ldots}_{=0}+\color{red}{\det\begin{pmatrix}-b-\\-c\\-a-\end{pmatrix}}$$$${}$$

$$=\color{red}{\det A}+\color{red}{\det A}=6$$

Answer (score 0):

I will use slightly different notation, write

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} v_{1}\\ v_{2}\\ v_{3}\end{bmatrix}$$ where $v_{i}$ are the rows of $A$ and  $\operatorname{det}(A) = 3.$

Then

$$\operatorname{det}\begin{bmatrix}
 v_{1} + v_{2}\\
v_{2} + v_{3}\\
v_{3} + v_{1}
\end{bmatrix} = \operatorname{det} \left(\begin{bmatrix} v_{1}\\ v_{2} \\v_{3} \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 &1 &0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\\ 1& 0& 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} v_{1}\\ v_{2}\\v_{3}\end{bmatrix}\right) = \operatorname{det}\left(A + \begin{bmatrix} 0 &1 &0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\\ 1& 0& 0\end{bmatrix}A \right)$$
So,
 $$\operatorname{det}(A)\operatorname{det}\left(I+\begin{bmatrix} 0 &1 &0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\\ 1& 0& 0\end{bmatrix}\right) = 6$$

Comment: Yup another answer just did this! Thanks for the indepth version tho

Comment: How did you arrive at the last step from the third step? Where did the $\det(A)$ on the outside come from?

Comment: Split the determinant over multiplication